# Getting error in installation of ejabberd 15.09

Tags: ejabberd

I installed ejabberd 15.09  from source code and erlang 18.0 from otp_src_18.0 file. I compile ejabberd with make and then it make install.  when i run ejabberd with ejabberdctl live command, its getting error msg as below:

```
[error] CRASH REPORT Process <0.271.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: no case clause matching [domain,server_host,pid,local_hint] in ejabberd_router:update_tables/0 line 396 in gen_server:init_it/6 line 352
11:15:59.202 [error] Supervisor ejabberd_sup had child undefined started with ejabberd_router:start_link() at undefined exit with reason no case clause matching [domain,server_host,pid,local_hint] in ejabberd_router:update_tables/0 line 396 in context start_error
11:15:59.230 [error] CRASH REPORT Process <0.41.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: no such process or port in call to gen_server:call(ejabberd_sup, {start_child,{ejabberd_sm,{ejabberd_sm,start_link,[]},transient,1000,worker,[ejabberd_sm]}}, infinity) in application_master:init/4 line 134
11:15:59.230 [info] Application ejabberd exited with reason: no such process or port in call to gen_server:call(ejabberd_sup, {start_child,{ejabberd_sm,{ejabberd_sm,start_link,[]},transient,1000,worker,[ejabberd_sm]}}, infinity)
```

anyone can help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You have a previous, old version of the database that is interfering. Delete Mnesia database and restart from scratch (if this is a development version and you can afford restart from blank database).

Note that latest version is 16.03 and it is probably the version you should use to start a new development.